# C++ equivalent to Java http request

Tags: c++, linux, httprequest, httpclient, http-get

Is there any equivalence in C++ to the following code in Java?

```
String url = "http://166.111.1.2/sensor?index=" + index_value;
HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpGet request = new HttpGet( url );
HttpResponse response = client.execute( request );
```

I want to impletement the http request in my C++ code on Linux, but I cannot find a way to do it. I can use the HttpClient Class on Windows platform though.

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is that there is nothing built into C++ to handle HTTP requests. You will need to use a third party or open source library like quantdev has suggested.

.NET has the class as you noted, but that is not part of the C++11 standard.